# Executing ImageMagick with exec PHP in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, imagemagick, exec

I have the following code:

```
...
$last_id = $row->id;

$justname2 = pathinfo($_FILES["pdf"]["name"], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$input2 = "C:/wamp/www/apuntes/components/com_djclassifieds/images/item/WM_".$_FILES["pdf"]["name"];
$output2 = "C:/wamp/www/apuntes/components/com_djclassifieds/images/item/".$last_id."_".$justname2.".png";
$justname3 = $last_id."_".$justname2;

exec('C:\"Program Files"\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\convert -density 400 '.$input2.'[0] -resize 25% '.$output2);
```

And it works perfectly on my Wamp Server.

The problem is when I upload this to the real server because I dont have the ImageMagick in C: but in /libraries. So I tried this:

```
exec(JPATH_ROOT."/libraries/ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16/convert -density 400 ".$input2." -resize 25% ".$output2);
```

But it is not working. Also tried JPATH_SITE.

I have to say that ImageMagick is not installed on the server, I just uploaded the installation folder.

Any clue or advice that could help?

Comment: Well...I found the solution. First of all, I needed to install the ImageMagick on the server. Then, I needed to restart the server. Finally, using this lane: exec(/usr/bin/convert -density 400 ".$input2." -resize 25% ".$output2);, it worked.

Comment: hey it is not working for me. Thruogh php it is working fine. Please give me solution ASAP.

Comment: I have already installed imageMagick in my system.